# doubled payment

Tags: electrum

I had one strange situation. I created payment transaction, broadcasted it but electrum couldn't execute request due timeout, network weren't accessible. Then after 10 minutes I created one more transaction, broadcasted and  gone two transactions to the network  old and new one, but I expected only one new transaction to go out. How to avoid such situations? Why did it do that?

Answer (score 1):

> **How to avoid such situations?**

You should be able to view the status of your first transaction in the `history` tab in Electrum. You can right click on a transaction to get some options to affect that transaction.

If using the Electrum daemon and command line you can use the `electrum history` command.

I suspect if you had seen a pending transaction, you wouldn't have created a duplicate.

> **Why did it do that?**

I guess it held onto the first transaction until the network became available and then sent it - that would usually be the most useful and helpful approach for a wallet.

Comment: I use electrum daemon, not a wallet. Also it didn't throw to the network on restore connection but after I broadcasted the second transaction

Comment: OK, I think you'll find you get better answers if you include that sort of information in your question.